# how to redirect wp past site without wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Client no longer wants Wordpress and wants new site in HTML5 CSS3. I have the past site map with links to past pages. Seeing he no longer has Wordpress how do you redirect the old wordpress pages without wordpress to new html pages. His links to old site are still active but goes no where seeing the pages are no longer on the server and have been down for two weeks. Small site 4 pages. Thanks Tim

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using WordPress, I am guessing that this is hosted on a Linux server. If so, you are able to create 301 redirects using the .htaccess file.

Here is an example
Old page: http://www.example.com/contact-us

Going to new page: http://www.example.com/contact.html

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/contact-us/?$ http://www.example.com/contact.html
```